# Change name of open text file

Tags: notepad++

I currently do this workaround

1. File > Open Containing Folder
2. Hit F2
3. Rename it
4. Reload it in notepad++

I want to make this process faster. Is there a quick way to rename a file currently in your notepad++ window?

If I do Save As, then the old document (with the old name) is still there. I don't want old files hanging around.

Comment: I think that's as fast as you can get without coding a renaming tool yourself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the name of open file in notepad++ by

```
File > Rename...
```

[image: Rename in Notepad++]

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for renaming files WITH moving them to another partition too (it can only be renamed and moved in the same partition).

Comment: It also doesn't work if I rename it to the same filename, but different casing(from lowertoUperCase or from UpperTolowercase). At least on windows.